# Is $y$ to the power of $\frac{1}{\infty}$ equals 1?

Tags: exponentiation, infinity

Is

$$y^{\frac{1}{\infty}} = 1 \quad ? $$

If that's correct. $\log_1 (1)$ will be solved.

Comment: What is $ y $ symbol ?

Comment: $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}x^{\frac{1}{n}} = x^{0} = 1$ for $x\neq 0$

Comment: $y^{1/\infty}$ is undefined, but $\lim_{x\to\infty} y^{1/x}=1.$ Not sure how this resolves $\log_11.$

Comment: $\infty$ is not a number, so you cannot casually perform arithmetic involving this. More precisely, infinity in this kind of business is always either geometric or topological, and so, how it works in each of the formulas should depend on the continuity property of the functions involved.

Answer (score 0):

For $y\in(0,\infty)$, $\lim_{x\to\infty} y^{1/x}=1$. For $y=0$, $\lim_{x\to\infty}y^{1/x}=0$.

Comment: But why is y^1/infinity indeterminate?

Comment: @MostafaShaker, You must be confusing the following two things: $$\lim_{y\to1}\lim_{x\to\infty}y^{1/x}=1,\qquad\lim_{(x,y)\to(\infty,1)}=\texttt{does not converge}.$$ That the "form" $1^{1/\infty}$ is indeterminate precisely refers to the fact that the second limit does not converge. Saying differently, the behavior of the function $y^{1/x}$ depends on the path of $(x,y)$ that approaches to $(\infty, 1)$. In the first limit, a very specific path towards $(\infty, 1)$ is chosen, so this does not contradict the second limit.

Comment: @MostafaShaker I don't know what you mean. It seems to me that I've determined what $\lim_{x\to\infty} y^{1/x}$ is for all real values of $y$ that make sense.

Comment: I've got a casio fx-991ES plus that rounds numbers that rounds to nine decimal places. For example $5^0.0001$ is 1.000160957(approximately) so $5^0.0000000001$ is 1(approximately). So, I see logically that in reality $5^1/infinity$ = 1(without approximating). Is my opinion right? I see sometimes that some equations are solved philosophicaly or arithmeticly. And then they crash

Comment: And I am new here, so $5^0.0..$ is wrong. I didn't mean 5⁰.00.... I meant ^0.000.... that was a typo